# How to make a javaScript library extendable with plugins

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, module

Let's say that i have this code as a javaScript library:

```js
(function(global) {

  var _private = function(x) {
    return x;
  };

  var doSome = function(x) {
    return x;
  };

  var extend = function(x) {
    // ?
  };

  // maybe some inits....
  var init= function(x) {
    // ?
  };

  var myLib = {
    doSome: doSome,
    extend: extend,
  };

  // CommonJS, AMD, script tag
  if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = myLib;
  } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(function() {
      return myLib;
    });
  } else {
    global.myLib = myLib;
  }

})(typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : window);
```

I want to make this library extendable with plugins, plugins that use private methods

Comment: the extend function should register new functions?

Comment: but how to! give me an example, try edit my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a closure, the private methods should stay private!
only `myLib` public functions **should** access the private methods.

On the other hand, you could use `eval()` for what you are trying to accomplish.

When calling eval() you can create a function on the local scope, so it will have access to the "private" closure methods.

Take a look at this example:

```
var x = 2;
var myLib = (function() {
    var myLib = {
        extend: extend
    };

    var x = 1;

    function extend(name, fn) {
        myLib[name] = function() {
            eval('var f = '+fn.toString());
            return f.apply(this,arguments);
        };
    }

    return myLib;
})();
myLib.extend('a', function() { return x; });
myLib.a();
```

Instead of returning `2` it will return `1`. and that's because it's creating the function on the local scope of `eval()` function call.
meaning it has access to the "private" members of the closure.

I wouldn't suggest on using this solution, unless you know what your doing. since you really shouldn't play too much with `eval()`.

Comment: I am just trying to extend the utilities, the scope will be the same, just like jquery.fn

Comment: jQuery.fn is a shortcut for jQuery.prototype.
You should be using the prototype for this kind of behavior.

Comment: what about fn.extend, it's for plugins!

Comment: as said before, jQuery.fn, is a shortcut for jQuery.prototype.
if you're trying to mimic the behavior you should declare the methods on the prototype.